# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence

Logs:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.kzn.shoppingbackend.dto.Category
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
    at com.kzn.shoppingbackend.daoImpl.CategoryDAOImpl.update(CategoryDAOImpl.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.update(Unknown Source)
    at com.kzn.shoppingbackend.test.CategoryTestCase.updateCategory(CategoryTestCase.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.kzn.shoppingbackend.dto.Category
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:773)
    ... 40 more
```

CategoryTestCase.java

```
public class CategoryTestCase {
    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
    private static CategoryDAO categoryDAO;
    private Category category;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.kzn.shoppingbackend");
        context.refresh();
        categoryDAO = (CategoryDAO)context.getBean("categoryDAO");
    }
    @Test
    public void updateCategory() {
        category = categoryDAO.get(2);
        category.setName("Lenovo");

        assertEquals("Successfully added a category inside the table!",true,categoryDAO.update(category));
    }
}
```

CategoryDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository("categoryDAO")
@Transactional
public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    /**
     * Method updating single Category
     * @return true if successful
     */
    @Override
    public boolean update(Category category) {
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(category);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

while trying to update detached entity passed to persist error are getting 
kindly help to solve this issue . why its not able to save as updated value while every thing is seems to perfect what could be the reason for failing to update the DB and getting Detached error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to use

> sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(category);

**update** not a **persist**